# populating a <ul> with github api data using angular 6 http module

Tags: angular

I've been fooling around with how to consume API data using Angular 6 and the http client module. I've got the get request working and data coming back. I'm now trying to populate an unordered list with the data which populates the list with the repo url's with the links to the specific repos.

Here is what I have in the repo.component.html:

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-item" *ngFor="let repo of repos">
    <a href="">{{repo.html_url}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This brings in the repo urls and puts them in a link, but obviously when you click on the link, it's not going to go to the right url.

I've looked at a lot of the documentation and can't find a specific example of how to do this. The Tour of Heros doesn't even use a real http client and I've tried various methods like router links and ngHref but none seem to work.

I know I'm missing something simple, I just can't figure it out. Any help to get the repo url to link to the actual url in the list would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind to the href property

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-item" *ngFor="let repo of repos">
    <a [href]="repo.html_url">{{repo.html_url}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```